# How to find out the location of the file in Struts?

Tags: java, servlets, struts, url-pattern

I want to know that how to find out the location of a file in Struts.
Where the files would be situated
Here is some part of program:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>config</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
```

I know that `.do` would be the extension of any file in the project but I am not getting its location. I don't know anything about struts.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Your `.do` is your URL pattern as (@Jigar Joshi mentioned) to see where it's mapped you will have to look at your URL on your browser:

Supposed your have `http://localhost:8080/myapp/login.do`, then the `.do` is seeing by your web container and it calls your Struts Servlet `org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet`.

The Struts `ActionServlet` will then see your relative path `/login` (see how I've ignored the `.do`) and see whether it's mapped on your `config` file (in your case `/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml`).

From there, Struts `ActionServlet` check if there's an action path that matches your relative path, something like this:

```
<action path="/login" type="com.myapp.action.LoginAction" name="LoginForm" scope="request">

</action>
```

If that `<action>` is found, Struts will call `com.myapp.action.LoginAction` class and call the `execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception` method (if the class is just a simple `Action` class).

I hope this helps.

---

Inside your `<action>` element you might find another element called `<forward>`, example:

```
<forward name="FHome" path="/content/jsp/home.jsp" />
```

The forward `name` attribute is basically what your Struts Action calls when it returns an `ActionForward`, a code like this:

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
     return mapping.findForward("FHome");
}
```

Bear in mind that a `forward` inside an `action` element in `struts-config.xml` is called a local forward. A Global Forward sits outside the `action` element.

The `path` of the `forward` element is the relative path of the jsp page that Struts has to call (and the web/servlet container) to render.

Hope this clears things out for you.

Comment: <action> found but still won't understand how to find out the actual path of the file; <action input="/index.jsp" 
   name="login_action_form" 
   parameter="method"
      path="/login" scope="session"
      type="com.hms.transaction.action.LoginAction" 
      validate="true">

Comment: Inside your `<action>` is your `input="/index.jsp"`. That's the file. It's somewhere in `web`/`webContent` folder (if you're using Eclipse).

Comment: I made a search on file index.jsp; got so many files but wasn't match with the code viewed in source while executing.

Comment: I have no idea what you're searching for. Struts tag gets generated to HTML which is presented to the client.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that .do would be the extension of any file in the projec

**No** , `.do` would be the URL pattern.

Whenever you hit `/yourapp/login.do` particular action is supposed to be executed in struts and that is mapped in `struts-config.xml`